# How to generate custom URL in yii with CHtml::link()?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

In my `CGridview` I have a link tag where I need to show the rewritten URL of the job post. Here is the code snippet of link I am using:

```
'apply' => array
(
    'name' => 'Apply',
    'value' => "CHtml::link('Apply', Yii::app()->commons->getJobURL($data->id), array('class' => 'button button-mini tright','target'=>'_blank'))",
    'type' => 'raw',
 )
```

In the Commons component I have a function `getJobURL($id)` that generates the complete URL of the job post like:

```
http://localhost/jobs/company-name/job-title
```

But my this function `Yii::app()->commons->getJobURL($data->id)` does not work because `$data` variable is not available like that in `CHtml::link()` function.

Is there any other way to achieve?

Comment: generate link in your model, call the model in your gridview.

Comment: Thanks @Criesto. Applied your suggestion and it works.